# Can you add two types of users onto jwt strategy auth?

Tags: mongodb, jwt

Im creating an admin dashboard for teachers to login and sign up and students to login and signup. I have setup jwt strategy and local strategy using passport.js. My question is can I implement both teachers and users onto jwt strategy passport using mongodb models?
here is my attempt.

```
const passport = require('passport');
const { Strategy: JwtStrategy, ExtractJwt } = require('passport-jwt');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local');
const { secret } = require('../config');
const Teacher = require('../models/Teacher');
const Student = require('../models/Student');
```

below i have my jwt strategy where I include users and teachers

```
     const jwtOptions = {
     jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromHeader('authorization'),
     secretOrKey: process.env.SECRET || secret,
     };

    const tjwtLogin = new JwtStrategy(jwtOptions, async (payload, done) => 
    {
    try {
    console.log('im hitting inside jwt')
    const user = await User.findById(payload.sub).select('-password');
    const teacher = await Teacher.findById(payload.sub).select('- 
    password');

      if (!user || !teacher) {
      return done(null, false);
    }
     
    return done(null, user || teacher );
    } catch (e) {
    return done(e, false);
    }

 

    });
```

```
here is my local strategy
```

```
const localOptions = { usernameField: 'email' };
const tlocalLogin = new LocalStrategy(localOptions, async (email, 
password, done) => {
try {
const user = await User.findOne({ email });
const teacher = await Teacher.findOne({ email });


 if (!user || !teacher) { return done(null, false); }
 const isMatch = await user.comparePassword(password);
 const isTMatch = await teacher.comparePassword(password);

if (!isMatch || !isTMatch ) { return done(null, false); }
 return done(null, user || teacher  );
} catch (e) {
return done(e);
}

});
```

here I define the strategy.

```
     passport.use(tjwtLogin,ulocalLogin);
     passport.use(tlocalLogin,ujwtLogin);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be alot of code and hardcoded conditions being used by you for the authentication part. As what if in future some new rule needs to be added.

What you can  do is use a single DB Model for users and add a extra parameter of typeofuser(student and teacher) in your case. And do the authentication using a single auth strategy and redirect the user based on role of user.

Answer (score 0):

here is a successful approach. check if users and students are not null.

```
const passport = require('passport');
const { Strategy: JwtStrategy, ExtractJwt } = require('passport-jwt');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local');
const { secret } = require('../tconfig');
const Teacher = require('../models/Teacher');
const User  = require('../models/User');

const jwtOptions = {
  jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromHeader('authorization'),
  secretOrKey: process.env.SECRET || secret,
};

const tjwtLogin = new JwtStrategy(jwtOptions, async (payload, done) => {

   try {
     const teacher = await Teacher.findById(payload.sub).select('-password');

     const user = await User.findById(payload.sub).select('-password');
     
     if(teacher){
      if (!teacher ) {
        return done(null, false);
      }
      return done(null, teacher );
     }

     if(user){
      if (!user ) {
        return done(null, false);
      }
      return done(null, user );
     }
  } catch (e) {
    return done(e, false);
  }

});

const localOptions = { usernameField: 'email' };
const tlocalLogin = new LocalStrategy(localOptions, async (email, password, done) => {

  try {
    const teacher = await Teacher.findOne({ email });
    const user = await User.findOne({ email });    
    if(teacher){
      if (!teacher ) { return done(null, false); }      
        const isMatch = await teacher.comparePassword(password);
        if (!isMatch) { return done(null, false); }
        return done(null, teacher  );
    }
    if(user){
      if (!user ) { return done(null, false); }
        const isMatch = await user.comparePassword(password);
        if (!isMatch) { return done(null, false); }
      return done(null, user  );
    }
 
  } catch (e) {
    return done(e);
  }
  
});

 
 passport.use(tjwtLogin);
 passport.use(tlocalLogin);
```